# Where am I going wrong with this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I am trying to solve:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{2^{nx}-2^x}{x}$$

I have tried L'Hopital's rule, but didn't really help. Any tips would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Any constraints on $n$?  $n<1$, $n>1$, and $n=1$ all behave differently.

Comment: If $n=1$, the fraction and its limit are zero. If $n\ne1$, L'Hospital rule does work.

Comment: @erictowers sorry, n is in positive natural numbers.

Comment: @user127700 Please include the L'Hopital's method you tried so we can inspect it for the problem.

Comment: L'Hospital's rule should simply it greatly. Try taking the natural logarithm of of the limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $n=1$ the answer is obvious.  For $n>1$, note that for sufficiently large $x$,

$$
\frac{2^{nx}-2^x}{x}=
\frac{2^x}{x} \Bigl( 2^{(n-1) x} -1 \Bigr) \geq
\frac{2^x}{x}.$$

Finally,

$$ \log \frac{2^x}{x} = x \log 2 -\log x \to \infty,$$

as $x\to\infty$ and hence

$$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{2^x}{x} =\infty,$$

also.

Comment: why can we take logs without the limit being affected?

Comment: If $g$ is continous then $\lim_{n\to\infty} z_n =a \Rightarrow$\lim_{n\to\infty} g(z_n)=g(a)$.  There are some minor issues with $a$ being infinite here, but one can leave those aside for the purpose of intuition.

Comment: Grrr, won't let me edit.

Answer (score 1):

We have 3 cases to consider:

1) If $n=1$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2^{nx}-2^x}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} 0 =0$.

2) If $n > 1$, then $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} \frac{2^{nx}-2^x}{x} = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^x(2^{(n-1)x}-1)}{x}$. Since $n>1$, we can see that both the numerator and denominator here go to $\infty$, so we may use L'Hopital's rule to get:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (\ln 2)(n2^{nx}-2^x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (\ln 2)(2^x)(n2^{(n-1)x}-1) = \infty$$

3) If $n < 1$, then in $\displaystyle \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}\frac{2^x(2^{(n-1)x}-1)}{x}$, the numerator goes to $-\infty$ and the denominator goes to $\infty$, so we may use L'Hopital's rule to get:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (\ln 2)(n2^{nx}-2^x) = \lim_{x\rightarrow\infty} (\ln 2)(2^x)(n2^{(n-1)x}-1) = -\infty$$

Comment: Your answer is correct but the OP specified in the comments that $n\in N$. So your case three isn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

For the case the n=1 the limit is obviously 0 but for the case that n>1 we begin by using L'Hospital's rule to simplify the expression giving $\lim_{x
\to \infty}$$ln(2)(n2^{nx}-2^x)$.
We then factor out $2^x$ giving $\lim_{x
\to \infty}$$ln(2)(2^x)(n2^{nx-1}-1)$.
We can then take the natural logarithm of the limit giving $\lim_{x
\to \infty}$$ln(ln(2)(2^x)(n2^{nx-1}-1))=\lim_{x
\to \infty}[ln(2^x)+ln(ln(2))+ln(n2^{nx-1}-1)]$=$\lim_{x
\to \infty}$$[xln(2)+ln(ln(2))+ln(n2^{nx-1}+1)]$=$\infty$
We then exponentiate which gives us $e^{\infty}$=$\infty$

Comment: I realize that the ln was not necessary after reexamining the problem. While unnecessary and more complicated than it need be it still gives the correct answer.